# Move files from Linux disk img to Windows to Linux server and keep permissions?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, permissions, mount, rsync

I have a backup disk image that I am trying to upload to my server. The problem is that the disk image is corrupted according to Linux. However, using DiskInternals Linux Reader on Windows I can open and view the entire disk.

I need to keep the exact permissions that are on the disk so I would ideally like to mount the disk image to a Linux VM and then rsync the files onto the server. However, I can't mount the img. When I run the repairs proposed by Linux it deletes all of the information of interest. For the record I can copy the files from the img to Windows so I know that the files are actually there still.

Any ideas as to how I can mount this image (which appears to be working in **some** capacity) to a Linux box so that I can move files without losing permissions?

Comment: Is it an image of a partition of a full disk (i.e. partition table included)? How exactly did you mount it in Linux?

Comment: @TomYan it's a `dd` of the entire disk.

Comment: Did you just `mount` it or `losetup -P` it first (coz you should)? http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/losetup.8.html

Comment: @TomYan I have attempted both and neither is successful.

Comment: @TomYan I am in the middle of running an epicly long disk repair.